# Codeigniter Validation for Multiple Upload Files in Single Input

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, file-upload

I am not new to codeigniter but i am new to uploading files in codeigniter,

I need to upload multiple files in codeigniter using single input field
Here is my view

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="PostMat" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="Title">
  <input type="file" id="MatFiles" multiple="" name="files[]">
  <button type="submit" name="Materials" class="btn">Submit</button>      
</form>
```

i used to library function for extending Multi Upload and Upload Validation

**Multiple Upload Library**
https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

**File Validation Library**
https://github.com/jeroen/codeigniter-extended-rules

I used this these two libraries, these two library functions are awesome of what i expected separately

*Here is my Controller:*

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('Title', 'title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules(NOIDEA_WHAT_COMES_ HERE,"files","required|file_allowed_type[png,bmp,jpg]|file_size_max[10]");
```

My Problem is i need to loop through the multiple files which i uploaded and i need to validate

I didnt get any problem in uploading files or getting properties of files, the only thing is what i need to mention in the place of "set rules" field_name,

or is there any simple idea to upload multiple files with validation

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [Multi Upload in CI](https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload)

Comment: Soyab , same thing i mentioned  above , My question not about multi upload, please ready my question one more time bro